# sql query on break on report statement

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g

write query to get result as below

```
emp     
----------------------------- 
       empno    ename   dept    sal     
      ------------------------------    
      1001       a      cse     1000                
      1211       b      cse     5000            
                      --------------- 
  sum                              6000             
                      ---------------
      3511       x      ese     4000
      1471       y      ese     3000    
                     ---------------- 
  sum                              7000
```

sum             -------------------------------------------                            13000

Comment: You must write some code and try something then submit your tired code and ask for help.

Comment: compute sum of sal on report
break on report
select * from emp where mgr is not null order by sal

Answer (score 0):

Sum of individual `dept`

```
select dept, sum(sal) as sal_sum
from emp
group by dept
order by dept
```

Total sum

```
select sum(sal) as total_sum
from emp
```